# Inconsistent build failure in Hudson due to grails-datastore-gorm-plugin-support:jar:3.1.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

Tags: mongodb, maven, grails, plugins, hudson

My application is developed in Grails 2.4.4. It uses MongoDB-3.0.2 plugin. I use Hudson as my CI system.

Sometimes when the job in hudson tries to build the application war, I get the below error.

```
Error | Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact
descriptor for
org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-plugin-support:jar:3.1.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
(Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

It doesn't happen all the time. Many times the war was built successfully. Recently I am facing this problem more frequently.

In one of the question similar to this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25510347/cannot-install-grails-mongodb-plugin), someone has suggested to change the Snapshot version to Release version. I tried it but didn't help me.

I also faced this problem in dev environment few times.

Can anyone let me know what could be the issuse? Could it be connectivity problem between the repository and my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our SSL certificate expired this morning.  We are working to get it addressed.  An option to use as a workaround would be to use `http` instead of `https`.  See comments at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9200.

The process is almost complete to get the new cert in place.  Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, The build was success without changing to http. Next time if it happens, I'll try http. Will it help in the future if I have a proxy repository?

Comment: Jeff, is the cert in place? Currently the build is failing.

Comment: Yes, I believe the cert is in place.

Comment: Ok. But I am not sure why the build failed. I tried with http and it worked