# Grails 2.5.0 + mongo + hibernate

Tags: mysql, mongodb, hibernate, grails

I am trying to use hibernate with mongo driver and experiencing some issues:

I have created brand new grails app, using grails 2.5.0. changed dataSource.groovy to point to mysql, uncommented mysql-connector-java:5.1.29 and everything works fine.

But when i am adding  **compile "org.grails.plugins:mongodb:5.0.0.RC1"** to plugins section in Build Config i get this on startup:

```
| Error 2016-02-22 14:32:29,439 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder.evaluateMapping
```

what am i missing?

**NB!**  App does not start, so all internal mappings don't matter at this point.

Here is my config files:

Datasource -> https://cldup.com/GnXUJDOy0b.txt

BuildConfig ->https://cldup.com/xtk5l1F_BW.txt

Error -> https://cldup.com/NJ7vpoX3Kb.txt

Answer (score 0):

It could be useful if you show more code but seems you are not setting the mapping for mongo in the domain class definition :

```
static mapWith="mongo"
```

[Here](https://etcpe9.wordpress.com/2012/01/28/beginning-grails-2-0-with-mongodb/) you can find an useful tutorial about this

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to make mongodb 5.0.1 to work, after days of searching found this answer. This solution worked.

```
plugins {
    compile (":mongodb:3.0.2") {
        excludes 'grails-datastore-gorm-plugin-support'
        excludes 'grails-datastore-gorm'
        excludes 'grails-datastore-core'
    }
}
```

and then in dependencies, pull the correct ones in:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-plugin-support:3.1.3.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm:3.1.3.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-core:3.1.3.RELEASE'
}
```

from here [Cannot install Grails MongoDB plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25510347/cannot-install-grails-mongodb-plugin)

Hope this will save someone a great deal of time and effort.